# Column-wise formulation CPLEX- Adding new constraint sets within columns

Tags: c, callable, cplex

I use callable library of C/C++ to code a set partitioning formulation. I use column-like formulation.
I have two clusters of constraints.

Whenever I add columns, I use:

```
for (i = 1; i <= colIdx ; i++) {   //For all columns
   ...
     status = CPXaddcols(env, lp, 1, colNum, obj, cmatbeg, cmatind , cmatval,
        lb, ub, NULL);}
```

However; colNum, cmatind and constraint senses are different for these two constraint sets. If I use another CPXaddcols for second constraint set, it adds new variables, but I just want to add new rows within given columns.

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add multiple rows (constraints) to your CPLEX problem with one call to `CPXaddcols.`

Just make sure that after your call `CPXcreateprob` and before you call the `CPXaddcols` above, you have called in the appropriate number of `CPXnewrows` to inform CPLEX that these constraints are non-zero.

As the CPLEX help states [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r4/index.jsp?topic=/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcallablelibrary/html/functions/CPXaddcols.html)

```
CPXaddcols cannot add coefficients in rows that do not already exist (that is, in rows with index greater than the number returned by CPXgetnumrows); 
[...]
The routine CPXnewrows can be used to add empty rows before adding new columns via CPXaddcols.
```

Also, just make sure that when you add your variable `colNum` is actually referring to the number of non-zero values that you are going to be adding in the new column.

[This example](http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/~diam/ro/online/ilog/examples/cplex/src/c/fixnet.c) has instances where each call of `CPXaddcols` adds the variable to two constraints.

Specifically look closely at this part of the code:

```
    /* Add flow variables */

   for (j = 0; j < NUMEDGES; j++) {
      ind[0] = orig[j];  /* Flow leaves origin */
      val[0] = -1.0;
      ind[1] = dest[j];  /* Flow arrives at destination */
      val[1] =  1.0;

      name[0] = buffer;
      sprintf(buffer, "x%d%d", orig[j], dest[j]);

      status = CPXaddcols (env, lp, 1, 2, &unitcost[j], &zero, ind, val,
                           NULL, NULL, name);
```

Hope that helps.